# how to get selected page number in kendo grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Hi i'm very much new to kendo UI, so need help in the below fix,

I'm using kendo grid UI as below for pagination:
`<script>`
`$(document).ready(function(){`
`$("#table3").kendoGrid({`
`dataSource: {`
`pageSize: 10`
`},`
`pageable: true,`
`enter code here`height: 300,
`sortable: true,`
});
`$("#table3").show();`
`});`
`</script>`

when user edits a record in a page, he's redirected to edit page with that record details so I need current page number because after editing a record in a page, I need to redirect user to the same page after saving the details of that record. 
I'm using this in a coldfusion page.
Please help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you are after is here :

http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/pager#methods-page

```
 // get the page
 var currentPage = grid.dataSource.page();

 // later set the page
 grid.dataSource.page(currentPage );
```

But I am bit confused with the redirect from the grid to edit page, why do you do that ? Kendo has inline batch edit and popup edit features, if you move to other page it will all get bit more complicated.

FYI : http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/editing.html

Comment: thank you very much for the help. Yes I implemented the pop up one of kendo UI, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
// declare page index as 1
    var currentPage = 1;

    pageable: {
    change: function (e) {  
    currentPage = e.index;
    },
    page: currentPage,
    sortable: true,
    ..`enter code here`
    }

    $scope.grid = dataSource;
    $scope.grid._page = currentPage;// stay in the current page after grid refreshes
```

Comment: Please explain your answer a bit more, see [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Correct answer. Use _page property on grid datasource object. this.gridDataSource = getDataSource();
this.gridDataSource._page = 2;